# Ivy: How can I execute an action on a selection without opening the action menu?

Tags: ivy, counsel

Apologies if the question is poorly formulated, I am a beginner at understanding internals of Emacs/packages.

I am using using Doom Emacs, which provides Ivy as an interface for, for example, finding files.

I understand that custom actions can be created for acting on candidates. In my case (with Doom's Evil bindings), I select a candidate and hit `C-o` to open the actions menus

I wrote a function that opens the selected file in a vertical split rather than in the current window, and added it as an action.

However, I would like to call this function directly by hitting a keyboard shortcut when I'm in Ivy (as I'm filtering files/buffers and selecting a candidate), instead of having the additional step of opening the actions menu.

So, for example, when I open ivy in my personal config folder and select the file I want, I would like to:

- Press `RET` to perform the default Ivy action (open the file in the current window)
- Press `C-v` to open the file in a vertical split using my custom function
- Possibly add more key mappings for other custom functions as well.

How might I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew Apologies!

Comment: No problem. Welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I would like to call this function directly when I'm in Ivy (as I'm filtering files/buffers and selecting a candidate), instead of having the additional step of opening the actions menu. How might I be able to accomplish this?

If I understood correctly, you're trying to set this function as the default action.

If you're calling `ivy-read` yourself, you can pass this function as the value of the `:action` keyword.  For example:

```el
(defun my-echo (&rest args)
  "Echo ARGS."
  (message ">>> %s" args))

(ivy-read "Echo: " '("a" "b" "c") :action #'my-echo)
```

You can also modify the action list of an existing command, for example:

```el
(ivy-add-actions #'ivy-switch-buffer '(("o" my-echo "echo")))
```

Here `"o"` is the default action key, so this will actually replace the previous default with `my-echo`.

For more on Ivy actions, see [`(info "(ivy) Actions")`](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#actions).

#### Edit

> Possibly add more key mappings for other custom functions as well.

If you're calling `ivy-read` directly, you can specify a custom keymap to be [composed](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Inheritance-and-Keymaps.html) with `ivy-minibuffer-map`, for example:

```el
(defun my-echo-candidate ()
  "Exit Ivy completion, echoing selected candidate."
  (interactive)
  (ivy-exit-with-action
   (lambda (cand)
     (message ">>> %s" cand))))

(ivy-read "Echo: " '("a" "b" "c")
          :keymap (easy-mmode-define-keymap '(("\C-v" . my-echo-candidate))))
```

Of course, to reuse your custom bindings, you can either create your own named keymap:

```el
(defvar my-ivy-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "\C-v" #'my-echo-candidate)
    map)
  "Keymap to compose with `ivy-minibuffer-map'.")
```

or modify `ivy-minibuffer-map` directly (see [`(info "(ivy) Minibuffer key bindings")`](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#minibuffer-key-bindings)).  This is probably your only option if you want to modify the minibuffer keymap of an Ivy command not under your direct control.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond! I wasn't clear in my question and omitted a critical part: Rather than replacing or modifying the default action, I would like to map a key to calling my custom action in Ivy. So in the same way as `RET` calls the default "open" action, I would like for example `C-v` to call my custom function. Any idea how I might be able to do that?

Comment: @gueorgui Thanks for clarifying. Let me know whether the updated answer addresses your question.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Accepted!